# how to mask first Five digit number on keyup using *

Tags: javascript

For eg while i am typing my ssn number my first 5 dight must be masked to *

```
  123456789    =>  *****6789
```

Note :***on keyup***  it should check no of digits and mask based on it.

I came through this below example. It mask the entire nine digit.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VROrdo

Comment: Do you expect that only numbers will be in the input, or are other characters allowed too?

Comment: yes only numbers will be given.no alphabetic or special character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your displayVal replace method regexr with following.

```
displayVal = displayVal.replace(/[0-9]+5/g,i=>"*****".slice(0,i.length));
```

Answer (score 8):

I modified your code to mask first 5 characters. Also this is bullet proof if someone paste a copied number.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLvRWw

```
// Replace first 5 numbers with astericks
if (displayVal.length < 6){
  displayVal = displayVal.replace(/[0-9]/g, '*'); 
}
else{
  displayVal = '*'.repeat(5) + val.slice(5);
}
```

Comment: The cases look like they have a slightly different behavior if `displayVal` isn't purely composed of digits, since the `true`-case replaces only digits with `'*'` while the `false`-case replaces all characters in the first 5 with `'*'`.